# Why does my javascript audio player work well on it's own but not in my Wordpress website?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, audio

So, I've developed a HTML5 + Javascript audio player and have a working solution here: http://jimkulakowski.com/games/audioPlayer.js/audioPlayer.html

I'm now trying to implement the player into my Wordpress site, but it's not working.  The console doesn't report any error with the script, but it also doesn't return logs.  Any ideas?  here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Audio Player</title>

<style>
#audioPlayerWrap {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #222;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 20px 5%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ccc;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#currentSong {
    width: 40%;
}

#audioplayer {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

#currentSong,
#audioplayer {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

#pButton {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center;
}

.play {
    background: url(play.png) no-repeat;
}

.pause {
    background: url(pause.png) no-repeat;
}

.play,
.pause {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#timeline {
    width: 70%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #444;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#playhead {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: -4px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px #333;
}

#time {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#exitPlayer {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 17px 20px;
    color: #aaa;
    background-color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#exitPlayer:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #D22929;
}

#playlist {}

.song-link {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.song-link:hover {
    color: red;
}

</style>

<audio id="music">
    <source id="mp3Source" src="#" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<div id="audioPlayerWrap">
    <div id="currentSong"></div>
    <div id="audioplayer">
        <button id="pButton" class="play"></button>
        <div id="timeline">
            <div id="playhead"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="time"></div>
        <div id="exitPlayer">X</div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="playlist">
  <div class="song-link" data="vice-avenue-demo-80k.mp3">Vice Avenue</div>
  <div class="song-link" data="icicle-drive-ext-loop-80k.mp3">Icicle Drive</div>
</div>

<script>
// Store elements
var audioPlayerWrap = document.getElementById('audioPlayerWrap');
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
var music = document.getElementById('music'); // id for audio element
var duration; // Duration of audio clip
var pButton = document.getElementById('pButton'); // play button
var playhead = document.getElementById('playhead'); // playhead
var timeline = document.getElementById('timeline'); // timeline
var timelineWidth = timeline.offsetWidth - playhead.offsetWidth; // timeline width adjusted for playhead
var onplayhead = false; /// Boolean value so that mouse is moved on mouseUp only when the playhead is released
var time = document.getElementById("time");
var exitPlayer = document.getElementById('exitPlayer');
var currentSong = document.getElementById('currentSong');
var audioSource = document.getElementById('mp3Source');
var songLink = document.getElementsByClassName("song-link");


// Event listeners
// Play/Pause button
pButton.addEventListener("click", pButtonClick, false);

// timeupdate event listener
music.addEventListener("timeupdate", timeUpdate, false);

// Gets audio file duration
music.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() {
    duration = music.duration;
}, false);

//Makes timeline clickable
timeline.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    moveplayhead(event);
    music.currentTime = duration * clickPercent(event);
}, false);

// Makes playhead draggable 
playhead.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);

// Exit button listener
exitPlayer.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Hide audio player
    audioPlayerWrap.style.opacity = 0;
    music.pause();
});

// Song link listener
// Get url and update audio src
var getData = function() {
    // Store attributes
    var songURL = this.getAttribute('data');
    var songName = this.innerHTML;

    // Set new attributes
    audioSource.setAttribute("src", songURL);
    currentSong.innerHTML = 'Now Playing ' + '"' + songName + '"';

    // Load and play audio
    music.load();
    playAudio();

    console.log('play audio');

    // Make audio player visible
    audioPlayerWrap.style.opacity = 1;
}

for (var i = 0; i < songLink.length; i++) {
    songLink[i].addEventListener("click", getData, false);
}

// Add play/pause spacebar funtionality
window.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    if (event.keyCode === 32) {
        playAudio();
        // Make audio player visible
        audioPlayerWrap.style.opacity = 1;
    }
});


// Functions
//Play and Pause
function playAudio() {
    // start music
    if (music.paused) {
        music.play();
        // remove play, add pause
        pButton.className = "";
        pButton.className = "pause";
    } else { // pause music
        music.pause();
        // remove pause, add play
        pButton.className = "";
        pButton.className = "play";
    }
}

// pButton click handler
function pButtonClick() {
    playAudio();
    console.log('clicked play');
}

// returns click as decimal (.77) of the total timelineWidth
function clickPercent(e) {
    return (e.pageX - timeline.offsetLeft) / timelineWidth;
}

// mouseUp handler
// getting input from all mouse clicks
function mouseUp(e) {
    if (onplayhead === true) {
        moveplayhead(e);
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveplayhead, true);
        // change current time
        music.currentTime = duration * clickPercent(e);
        music.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeUpdate, false);
    }
    onplayhead = false;
}

// mousemove handler
// Moves playhead as user drags
function moveplayhead(e) {
    var newMargLeft = e.pageX - timeline.offsetLeft;
    if (newMargLeft >= 0 && newMargLeft <= timelineWidth) {
        playhead.style.marginLeft = newMargLeft + "px";
    }
    if (newMargLeft < 0) {
        playhead.style.marginLeft = "0px";
    }
    if (newMargLeft > timelineWidth) {
        playhead.style.marginLeft = timelineWidth + "px";
    }
}

// mouseDown handler
function mouseDown() {
    onplayhead = true;
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveplayhead, true);
    music.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeUpdate, false);
}

// timeUpdate 
// Synchronizes playhead position with current point in audio 
function timeUpdate() {
    var playPercent = timelineWidth * (music.currentTime / duration);
    playhead.style.marginLeft = playPercent + "px";
    // Check if music has ended
    if (music.currentTime === duration) {
        pButton.className = "";
        pButton.className = "play";
        audioPlayerWrap.style.opacity = 0;
    }
    // Update timer
    time.innerHTML = readableDuration(music.currentTime);
}

// Convert time to readable format
function readableDuration(seconds) {
    sec = Math.floor(seconds);
    min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
    min = min >= 10 ? min : '0' + min;
    sec = Math.floor(sec % 60);
    sec = sec >= 10 ? sec : '0' + sec;
    return min + ':' + sec;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Is it a display or sound problem?

Comment: @Gael it seems to be both.  Nothing is happening on the screen and the audio is not playing.  Again, the console is not logging anything either, no errors or console.logs.

Comment: despite the FILE_NOT_FOUND errors, your code works for me.

Comment: Right!  It works for me too!...outside of my wordpress site...

Comment: Can you take a look here?: http://jimkulakowski.com/downloads/vice-avenue/

Comment: It is also works! Try to clear your cache

Comment: I've been rebuilding it in jQuery.  That may be what you saw.

Comment: There is still an error, but with twitterfeed.js, which must have stop the execution and disabled the controls of your audio player.

Comment: @gael  Thanks for the suggestions.  I've disabled the twitter feed and now have an error on the player.  It seems to be an anonymous function error.  Apparently the timelineWidth variable is returning a value of null. 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "offsetWidth" of null'

Comment: You are initializing the player before the DOM has been loaded. You can put the `<script src="audioPlayer.js" ></script>` on the bottom of your body, or at least after the player markups.

Comment: So I moved the player and the script into the footer, placed just before the '</body>' tag.  I still have the same error.  Any other ideas?

Comment: The script is executing after the markups.

Comment: now it is working for me, not for you?

Comment: I've rewritten it in jQuery and it's working now.  Thanks for your help.